# Printing something specific if it's the first, second and last thing being printed

Tags: java, arrays

How do I write code so that if there two things are printed, there's an "and" between them and if it's the element being printed, it has an "and" like this:
"1 100 dollar bill and 2 200 dollar bills" "1 100 dollar bill, 2 200 dollar bills and 4 10 dollar bills"

```
public class kassa {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner pengarinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner prisinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner betalsumma = new Scanner(System.in);
        int     belopp, rest, summa, pris, v=0, antalsedlar=0, antalvarv=0;
        String  tu="tusenlapp", fh="femhundralapp", th="tvahundralapp", eh="enhundralapp",
                ft="femtiolapp", tj="tjugolapp", ti="tiokronors mynt", f="femkronorsmynt", t="tvakronorsmynt",
                et="enkronorsmynt";

        String pengar [] = {tu, fh, th, eh, ft, tj, ti, f, t, et};
        int sedlar[] = {1000, 500, 200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1};
        System.out.println("Hur mycket ska du betala i kontant?");
        belopp = pengarinput.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Hur mycket kostar varan?");
        pris =  prisinput.nextInt();
        rest = belopp-pris;

        while(rest>0) {
            if(rest>=sedlar[v]) {
                for(int i = 0; i<sedlar.length-1; i++) {
                    if(rest<sedlar[v]) {
                        antalsedlar=0;
                        v++;
                    }
                    while(rest>=sedlar[v]) {
                        antalsedlar++;
                        rest-=sedlar[v];
                    }
                    if(antalsedlar!=0) {
                        antalvarv++;
                        if(antalvarv!=0) {
                            if(antalsedlar==1 && sedlar[v]>=20) {
                                System.out.print(antalsedlar + " st " + pengar[v] + "ar " + ", ");
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.print(antalsedlar + " st " + pengar[v] + " " + ", ");

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                antalsedlar=0;
                v++;
            }
        }
        if(pris>belopp) {
            System.out.println("Du har inte råd!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that using three `Scanner`s is unnecessary. You could just call `nextInt()` multiple times on the same instance.

Comment: Also note that you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; and class names should be written in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

Use a StringBuilder and basic conditions.  In the following, we concatenate an array of Strings but you can generalize it to any type for which you can generate a String.

```
public String concat(String[] values) {
  if (null == values) return "null";
  if (values.length == 0) return "";
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(values[0].trim());
  for (int index = 1 ; index < values.length ; ++index) {
    String op = index < (values.length - 1) ? ", " : " and ";
    sb.append(op).append(values[index].trim());
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regardless to your code which is fairly hard to read and decipher, I provide you two ways to compose such sentence. Suppose there is an initial array, such as:

```
String[] array = {"1100 USD", "2200USD", "3300 USD", "4400 USD"};
```

Here you go, the solutions expect at least one item in the `array`:

1. Using `StringBuilder` and `for-loop` iteration:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();          // initialize StringBuilder
   if (array.length == 1) {                         // special case of one element
       sb.append(array[0]);
   } else {                                         // or 2+ elements
       for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { // iterate all of them except the last one
           sb.append(array[i]);                     // ... always append an item
           if (i < array.length - 2) {              // ... if is not the last one, append ','
               sb.append(", ");
           } else {                                 // ... else append 'and' delimiter
               sb.append(" and ");
           }
       }
       sb.append(array[array.length - 1]);          // finally append the remaining item
   }
   String sentence = sb.toString();                 // composed sentence from StringBuilder
   ```
2. Using `StringBuilder` and `String.join` method:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();                      // initialize StringBuilder
   if (array.length == 1) {                                     // special case of one element
       sb.append(array[0]);
   } else {                                                     // or 2+ elements
       int len = array.length - 1;                              // length - 1
       String[] noLastWord = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, len); // array with no last word
       String initialSentence = String.join(", ", noLastWord);  // words connected with ','
       sb.append(initialSentence)                               // composing the sentence
         .append(" and ")                                       // ... with 'and'
         .append(array[array.length - 1]);                      // ... and the remaining word
   }
   String sentence = sb.toString();                             // composed sentence
   ```

   This can be packed to something more compact and readable:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
   if (array.length == 1) {
       sb.append(array[0]);
   } else {
       String initialSentence = String.join(", ", Arrays.copyOfRange(array, 0, array.length - 1));
       sb.append(initialSentence).append(" and ").append(array[array.length - 1]);
   }
   String sentence = sb.toString();
   ```